# How do I ensure an array operation is done by value rather than reference in ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm new to ruby and was wondering how I'd go about this

For example:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = []

b.push(a)
a.pop
a.pop

print b
# => [[1,2]]
```

I was expecting b to remain [[1,2,3,4]]

a seems to be pushed into b by reference, rather than value. I'd like b to stay as it is regardless of what I do to a in the future; how do I go about doing this in Ruby?

Comment: `b` remains the same after `a = [1, 2]`. The assignment doesn't affect the array in `b` at all.

Comment: oh, so it does. however, if i do a.pop instead of a = [1,2], i found the value of b changed. i've modified the original question

Comment: No, the value of `b` *doesn't* change. It still points to the same object as before (which is, incidentally, the same object that `a` also points to). *What* changes is the internal state of the object, but that is something completely different.

Comment: You pass copy of the object, using `dup`, for example `b.push(a.dup)`. But be aware that it's only a shallow copy and if `a` holds a reference for other object, this object won't be copied.

Comment: "By reference" and "by value" are not really very helpful terms in Ruby.  Strictly speaking, *all* parameters are passed by value. But sometimes the thing that is passed by value is a reference, so if you change it, you are effectively changing the value of the thing that is passed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a` is an array reference, so to push its *value* into `b`, you'll need to copy it:

```
b.push(a.dup)
```

This is similar to using `strdup` in C, where strings are pointers.

Comment: I don't think "value" is the correct term. `a.dup` merely creates a copy, i.e. a new array containing the same elements.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `splat` operator and push elements of `a` into `b` instead of whole array `a`.

```
b.push(*a)
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

If you wanted to push an array, then, use

```
b.push([*a])
#=> [[1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: `b.concat(a)` is another option for the first.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yeah, I had looked at `concat` - but for some reason I could not write `b.push([*a])` (the one pushes an array) using `concat`